# Most efficient way of determing which ID does not have a pair?

Tags: r, dataframe

Say that I have a dataframe that looks like the one below. In the dataframe we have the following pairs of IDs (4330, 4331), (2333,2334), (3336,3337), which are +/- 1 of each other. However, 3349 does not have pair. What would be the most efficient way of filtering out unpaired IDs?

```
   ID sex zyg race SES
1 4330   2   2    2   1
2 4331   2   2    2   1
3 2333   2   2    1  78
4 2334   2   2    1  78
5 3336   2   2    1  18
6 3337   2   2    1  18
6 3349   2   2    1  18
```

Comment: This is pretty easy to solve, so here's a hint: handle ID-pairs by looking at the smaller of the two values i.e. sort each of them. Then you're simply looking for when `diff(df$ID) == +1` Corner-case: how would you treat 4330, 4331, 4332? Do you say that is one pair and a singleton (which) or two (overlapping) pairs?

Comment: If there was a case where I had 4330, 4331, 4332, then they would be considered triplets. The pairs refer to twins.

Comment: Ok, so post your code attempt based on my hint, show us the output then tell us where you got stuck. That's what [SO rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) require. You can't just post a spec and ask for code.

Comment: Understood. Here's my pathetic attempt:

Comment: newdata <- wide_desc[order(wide_desc$ID),] 
which(diff(newdata$ID) == +1)

Comment: So do you want your output to contain all unpaired rows ("IDs do not have a pair") and also triplets(/quadruplets etc.)?

Comment: I would like my output to contain only paired rows and would also like to exclude triplets (if any). Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Should quadruplets and up be excluded too?

Comment: As far as I know, there aren't any quadruplets in the dataset, but why not for same measure!

Comment: Ok. Just for future reference, your question title and body appeared to be asking for the opposite. I guess you meant *"filter out unpaired IDs"*.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention, my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

This will return only pairs/twins (no unpaired or triplets, quadruplets, etc.). In base R:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1:3, 4330, 4331, 2333, 2334, 3336, 3337, 3349), sex = 2)
df <- df[order(df$ID),]
df[
  rep(
    with(
      rle(diff(df$ID)),
      cumsum(lengths)[lengths == 1L & values == 1]
    ), each = 2
  ) + 0:1,
]
#>     ID sex
#> 6 2333   2
#> 7 2334   2
#> 8 3336   2
#> 9 3337   2
#> 4 4330   2
#> 5 4331   2
```

Explanation:

After sorting the data, only individuals in a group (a twin, triplet, etc.) will have an ID difference of 1 from the individual in the next row. `diff(df$ID)` returns the difference in `ID` value from one row to the next along the whole `data.frame`. To identify twins, we want to find where `diff(df$ID)` has a `1` that is by itself (i.e., neither the previous value nor the next value is also `1`). We use `rle` to find those lone `1`s:

```
rle(diff(df$ID))
#> Run Length Encoding
#>   lengths: int [1:8] 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#>   values : num [1:8] 1 2330 1 1002 1 12 981 1
```

Lone `1`s occur when both the value of `diff(df$ID)` (`values`) and the length of runs of the same value (`lengths`) are both `1`. This occurs with the third, fifth, and eighth run. The starting rows (within `df`) of all runs are given by `cumsum(lengths)`, so we subset them at 3, 5, and 8 to get the starting index of each twin pair in `df`. We repeat each of those indices twice with `rep(..., each = 2)` then add `0:1` (taking advantage of [recycling in R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf)) to get the indices of any individual who is a twin.

Comment: Thank you, this looks great. I'm new to R and want to understand code that people suggest. Could you elaborate on what's going on here exactly? Thanks again.

Comment: @ericm, I added an explanation at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr::lag()` and `lead()`, you can `filter()` to rows where the previous `ID` is `ID - 1` or the next `ID` is `ID + 1`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(lag(ID) == ID - 1 | lead(ID) == ID + 1)
```

```
# A tibble: 6 × 5
     ID   sex   zyg  race   SES
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  4330     2     2     2     1
2  4331     2     2     2     1
3  2333     2     2     1    78
4  2334     2     2     1    78
5  3336     2     2     1    18
6  3337     2     2     1    18
```

*edit, this will *not* filter out "triplets," "quadruplets," etc., contrary to the additional requirements mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Nice. But OP said they want all unpaired rows, so the inverse. (still not clear do they want to also include triplets).