# Retaining row pairs and excluding singlets and triplets

Tags: r, dataframe

Say that I have a data frame like this....

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("2280", "2280","2280","2280","3115","2281", "2281","2281","2281", "3282","3282","3282","3282", "3283","3283","3283","3283","1821","1822", "4007", "1145", "1145", "1146", "1147"), sib_ID = c("2282", "2282", "2282", "2282", "3117", "2282", "2282", "2282", "2282", "3284", "3284", "3284","3284", "3284", "3284", "3284", "3284", "1823", "1823","4009", "1148", "1148","1148", "1148"), Age = c("3", "12", "6", "9", "3","9", "6", "12","3","9", "6", "12","3","9", "6", "12", "6", "12","12", "6", "12","12", "6", "6"), Behavior = c("good", "bad", "good", "bad", "good", "good", "good", "bad", "good", "good", "good", "bad","good", "good", "good", "bad", "good", "bad", "good","good", "bad", "good","good", "good"))

> df
     ID sib_ID Age Behavior
1  2280   2282   3     good
2  2280   2282  12      bad
3  2280   2282   6     good
4  2280   2282   9      bad
5  3115   3117   3     good
6  2281   2282   9     good
7  2281   2282   6     good
8  2281   2282  12      bad
9  2281   2282   3     good
10 3282   3284   9     good
11 3282   3284   6     good
12 3282   3284  12      bad
13 3282   3284   3     good
14 3283   3284   9     good
15 3283   3284   6     good
16 3283   3284  12      bad
17 3283   3284   6     good
18 1821   1823  12      bad
19 1822   1823  12     good
20 4007   4009   6     good
21 1145   1148  12      bad
22 1145   1148  12     good
23 1146   1148   6     good
24 1147   1148   6     good
```

and I want my data frame to only consist of IDs that have a pair. So we would keep data from (2280, 2281), (3282, 3283), (1821, 1822) and remove cases where the ID does not have a pair (3115 and 4007) and cases where we have a triplet (1145, 1146, 1147). What would be the most efficient way to go about doing this?

Example of desired output:

```
> df
     ID sib_ID Age Behavior
1  2280   2282   3     good
2  2280   2282  12      bad
3  2280   2282   6     good
4  2280   2282   9      bad
6  2281   2282   9     good
7  2281   2282   6     good
8  2281   2282  12      bad
9  2281   2282   3     good
10 3282   3284   9     good
11 3282   3284   6     good
12 3282   3284  12      bad
13 3282   3284   3     good
14 3283   3284   9     good
15 3283   3284   6     good
16 3283   3284  12      bad
17 3283   3284   6     good
18 1821   1823  12      bad
19 1822   1823  12     good
```

Comment: I don't see the logic of grouping. I initially thought it was by `ID`, but since you somehow combine 1145 and 1147 into a "triplet", I do not understand.

Comment: @r2evans My apologies, that was a typo. It's corrected now. 1145, 1146, and 1147 would be a triplet.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the issue, though. How do you group them together? Are you saying you want to consider every possible combination of `ID`s such that those that are singularly large enough should be considered on their own, but smaller ones have to be combined in various combinations?

Comment: IDs that have a difference of 1 would be considered a pair. For instance, 2280 and 2281 would be a pair. But 2280 and 3115 would not be. If it helps, this is twin data, so 2280 would correspond to twin1 and 2281 would correspond to twin2.

Comment: if 2280 and 2281 are strongly related and you are studying twins, i suggest you create a siblings id column upstream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First*, I think we need to clarify and solidify the grouping of IDs. I suggest we create a frame up-front to clearly identify these groups, then join back into the original data.

```r
GRPs <- data.frame(ID = as.integer(sort(unique(df$ID)))) %>%
  mutate(GRP = c(0, cumsum(diff(ID) > 1)), ID = as.character(ID))
GRPs
#      ID GRP
# 1  1145   0
# 2  1146   0
# 3  1147   0
# 4  1821   1
# 5  1822   1
# 6  2280   2
# 7  2281   2
# 8  3115   3
# 9  3282   4
# 10 3283   4
# 11 4007   5
```

From here, we join them back in and then do the grouped determination of "complete" or not.

```r
left_join(df, GRPs, by = "ID") %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(keep1 = all(c("good", "bad") %in% Behavior)) %>%
  group_by(GRP) %>%
  mutate(keep2 = all(c("good", "bad") %in% Behavior)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  dplyr::filter(keep1 | keep2)
# # A tibble: 22 × 6
#    ID    Age   Behavior   GRP keep1 keep2
#    <chr> <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <lgl> <lgl>
#  1 2280  3     good         2 TRUE  TRUE 
#  2 2280  12    bad          2 TRUE  TRUE 
#  3 2280  6     good         2 TRUE  TRUE 
#  4 2280  9     bad          2 TRUE  TRUE 
#  5 2281  9     good         2 TRUE  TRUE 
#  6 2281  6     good         2 TRUE  TRUE 
#  7 2281  12    bad          2 TRUE  TRUE 
#  8 2281  3     good         2 TRUE  TRUE 
#  9 3282  9     good         4 TRUE  TRUE 
# 10 3282  6     good         4 TRUE  TRUE 
# # … with 12 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Though it's returning more rows ...

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful! One question: my actual dataframe has 30 columns and I would like to retain them for each case that ends up getting included, how would I modify this accordingly?

Comment: I have no idea: nothing I do here relies on anything other than `ID` and `Behavior`, and that's the only thing you included in your logic. Are you saying that you have 30-something "Behavior"-like columns, and you have complex logic for how to consider a set "triplet", "double", or whatever?

Comment: I have 30 similar columns, yes. To help clarify the "grouping" issue, I made similar thread a month ago and was able to find a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74803511/most-efficient-way-of-determing-which-id-does-not-have-a-pair

Comment: The difference in this case, however, is that each ID now has multiple cases (ie. data that was collected at several ages, hence why you see 2280 repeating. The grouping logic for a double/triplet is fairly intuitive, but maybe I'm just not clear.... 2280 and 2281 would be a twin pair. 3282 and 3283 would be another twin pair. 1145, 1146, 1147 would be a triplet. Maybe it's not clear in my example because each child had data that was collected at several ages. But the grouping is the same. 2280 corresponds to one twin in the pair and 2281 corresponds to the other twin in the pair.

Comment: @ericm, you seem to be strugling with this "filter only twins" issue for quite some time, I strongly suggest you create a consistent "sibblings_ID" variable and save it in your data.frame, it could save you a lot of trouble. This information is too important to be calculated with obscure logic every time

Comment: Understood. The dataframe has a siblings_ID variable ("momID") that I use to convert my dataframe into wide format (with Twin_1 and Twin_2 on one row...). However, I don't see how the siblings_ID variable is necessary for trying to accomplish what I'm trying to do here. If it helps, I can edit my original post and include the siblings_ID column.

Comment: @GuedesBF Included the siblings_ID variable.

Comment: I meant an id for each family